# Set url twig by value Jquery

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony and twig template.
My code:

```
var dataId = $('.url-select').data('id');
url = "{{ url('product', {id: 'dataId'}) }}";
```

It not working.Do you have some solution, if this is possible?

Comment: you can't interact with the template via javascript; by the time the js can run, the template is already turned into html. this will never work.

Comment: you need to generate the url's beforehand; for example you can just set the full url in a data-attribute the same way

Comment: It's possible with [FosJsRouting](https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html)

Comment: you can assign a JS var then pass that as the route.

<script>
var myroute = "{{ path('myroutename') }}";
</script>

I have done this in other projects and it will pass the route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This short article answer to your question: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/server-data.html

In your twig template:

```html
<div class="url-select"
     data-id="{{ product.id }}"
     data-url="{{ path('product', {id: product.id}) }}">
</div>
```

And in js you can just select the url by doing this:

```js
var id = $('.url-select').data('id')
var url = $('.url-select').data('url')
```